# Logstash indexer is scalable?

Tags: logging, logstash

I am using logstash shipper -> redis -> logstash indexer -> elastricsearch -> kibana

I understand that redis and elastricsearch are designed to be scalable.
How about logstash indexer, I only see on logstash main site show an example of using only single logstash indexer.

Would that be enough to handle all logs? and what is your suggestion on having many instances of logstash indexer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your indexer really is the bottleneck of such a setup, you could easily add a second Logstash indexer on a second machine with the same configuration, where you only change the redis source host and the elasticsearch target host. When they read from the same redis instance, they use blocking reads to ensure that one redis entry is read by exactly one indexer.

As with all the components, they are especially good at horizontal scaling (more machines), but the indexer can also be scaled onto a bigger machine.

If the processing of single log events takes too long, you may try to prevent work on the indexer. This could e.g. be done by doing some work on the shipper side (using Logstash filters) or by having the applications write JSON logs instead of "plain" loglines.

Comment: Normally, do we really need multiple instances of indexers and how big scale have you seen a case that we need multiple instances of indexer?

Comment: If you have thousands of logs per second, why would you NOT have multiple indexers? You asked the question, so I answered it accordingly :-)

Comment: Yes, that's right. I am just starting to use it and just curious about indexer scalability and a case when we need multiple instances of indexers. I got all the answers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When deploying a 'bigger' machine, set the number of workers equal to the number of cores in the system. You can set this using a command-line flag.

From: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/flags

-w, --filterworkers COUNT
Run COUNT filter workers (default: 1)

You can also do some tests to see if this is the optimal value for you, in my case it was. You don't need extra instances on one machine.